# How to generate values for case class parameters in scala

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have a case class with 250 fields:

```
case class Data(field1:String, field2:Int, .. )
```

Is there a way to use scala check to generate values for its parameter

Irrelevant questions I've looked at:
[How to generate case objects for every field in a Scala case class using macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442722/how-to-generate-case-objects-for-every-field-in-a-scala-case-class-using-macro)
[Dynamically generate case class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583283/dynamically-generate-case-class-in-scala)
[Create an Arbitrary instance for a case class that holds a `Numeric` in ScalaCheck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724879/create-an-arbitrary-instance-for-a-case-class-that-holds-a-numeric-in-scalache)

Comment: You could use the `Generic` approach from the shapeless library to transform an `HList` to a case class instance. There is an example here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/csv.scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [scalacheck-shapeless](https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless):

```
import org.scalacheck.Shapeless._
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary._

implicitly[Arbitrary[Data]]
```

The above snippet does the following:

- Summon a `shapeless.Generic[Data]` via implicit macro to transform you case class into a `shapeless.HList`
- Recursively obtain all `Arbitrary[String]`, `Arbitrary[Int]` and so on for every field
- Assemble all that into a new `Arbitrary[Data]` instance